# How to find a contact using a Custom Field in Infusionsoft?

Tags: infusionsoft

I want to search a contact based on a custom field and I'm searching it using Data Query in Contact table but I'm getting an error saying Contact. does not exist.

What is the correct of searching contact by custom field?

Comment: That should work. Custom fields need to have an "_" prefix. Otherwise, you might add more detail to get a good answer.

Comment: Adding _ as prefix worked.